# Как изменить цвет данного окна в vs 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не вижу текст в этом окне. 
 Хочу изменить фон этого элемента, но я не знаю, как оно называется.

Comment: Это Intellisense Tooltip. Вам - [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787913/9921853)